# javascript element as a variable

Tags: javascript

```
var x = "card";    
document.nick.x.value = card_dealt;
```

Not quite sure what do do here. I googled this a bunch and came up with [] but they didn't work or I'm not using them right.

Comment: Are you trying to get the element with the id equal to `x`? (in this case, `"card"`)? If not what are you trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets.

```
var x = "card";
document.nick[x].value = card_dealt;
```

This lets you use the evaluation an expression as the property name.